# EF Core Migrations - Add new column with unique index ot existing database

Tags: .net-core, indexing, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have an existing table with data and I want to add a new column to it.

I have to set a default value for the column, but its complaining about it when I execute my migration. If I do not set a default value, it will also complain because all the values are null, which is also not unique.

Error:

> The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key
> was found for the object name 'powder.PowderBox' and the index name
> 'IX_PowderBox_Code'. The duplicate key value is (...).

**Configuration**

```
builder.Property(x => x.Code)
       .IsRequired()
       .HasMaxLength(14);

builder
   HasIndex(x => x.Code)
   IsUnique();
```

**Migrations:**

```
migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
   name: "Code",
   schema: "powder",
   table: "PowderBox",
   type: "nvarchar(14)",
   maxLength: 14,
   nullable: false,
   defaultValue: "...";

migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
   name: "IX_PowderBox_Code",
   schema: "powder",
   table: "PowderBox",
   column: "Code",
   unique: true);
```

How can I add a new column to an existing table with a unique index?

Comment: Do you have a plan for making the column values unique? If so, create the new column without the unique index, update the data to be unique, and then add the unique index.

Comment: That is it pretty much. Create the table without the unique constraint, add the data, declare the constraint at the end again and you should be good to go.

Comment: @pjs, I cannot expect every developer working on the project to do this...

Comment: See comment above @MKougiouris